# System.DirectoryServices.Protocol LDAP query results in unknown error returned from LDAP server

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am attempting to use System.DirectoryServices.Protocol to perform an LDAP query that I was able to perform successfully previously when I was using the Novell library.
Specifically, I am creating the connection and binding using

```
_ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
                new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(host, port, false, false),
                new NetworkCredential(userName: "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com", password: "mypassword"),
                AuthType.Basic
            );
_ldapConnection.Bind();
```

And then doing the following query

```
string searchBase = "DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com";
            string filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))";
            var search = new SearchRequest(searchBase, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, null);
            var response = (System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchResponse)_ldapConnection.SendRequest(search, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

However, doing so results in the following error

```
Unhandled exception. System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: An unspecified operation error occurred.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponseAsync(Int32 messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut, Boolean sync)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
```

I don't understand why this is happening because as far as I can tell, I should find all the users that are people, since [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) says that SearchScope.Subtree should

> Search the base object and all child objects. The value is equal to 2.

Any suggestions? It should be noted that If I add "CN=Users" to `searchBase` I am able to find users (but I don't understand why, and don't expect needing to do this since I did not need it in the Novell library. Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: I unpacked every property in the exception itself, and in the corresponding response attached to the exception. This is what I found:

```
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
Help Link: 
HResult: -2146233088
InnerException: 
Message: An unspecified operation error occurred.
Source: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
StackTrace:    at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponseAsync(Int32 messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut, Boolean sync)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at Keep_LdapCore.LdapService.LogUsers() in /workspaces/Keep-LdapCore/LdapService.cs:line 35
TargetSite: Void MoveNext()
Response.Controls: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl[]
Response.Error Message: Referral:
ldap://ForestDnsZones.inc.company.com/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com
ldap://DomainDnsZones.inc.company.com/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com
ldap://inc.company.com/CN=Configuration,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com
Response.MatchedDN: 
Response.Referral: System.Uri[]
Response.RequestId: 
Response.Result Code: -1
```

Comment: The `DirectoryOperationException` has a `DirectoryResponse` property. Can you share its contents? See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.directoryoperationexception.response) You could also test your request from a LDAP browser to see if you have a more undestandable message (ie. Administrative limit excedeed).

Comment: @MaxXapi I added the information you requested in my edit above. As per your suggestion to use an LDAP browser, using ApacheDirectoryStudio and constructing the query as I am programmatically above, I am able to find all the people in the subtree of the base that I specify that I expect.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give a lot of clues. Could you try the most low level thing, a ldapsearch: `ldapsearch -h yourHost -p yourPort -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com" -W -b "DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com" "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))"`

Comment: @MaxXapi the ldapsearch is successful in retrieving the results I expect. It should be noted that I am running the app in [.Net 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) in a Docker container.

Comment: I could suggest you try from a simple console app in order to exclude a problem related to the container (and/or with a stable .NET version instead of the 5 one), but it would not explain why your code works with `CN=Users,DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com` as search base but not with `DC=inc,DC=company,DC=com`. Which is, from my point of view, the weirdest element

Comment: @MaxXapi So running outside of a container on Linux with .NET 5 does not fix the issue. However, running it on Windows with .NET 3.1 does fix the issue. Won't know if its a Linux issue or a .NET 5 issue until I install the .NET 5 SDK on Windows. Really strange error either way.

Comment: If you have access to it, you could also check your LDAP server logs to see what's really sent to him. In the worst case you could also use a tool like Wireshark